# How to cast from unsigned long to void*?

Tags: c++, file-io, casting

I am trying to `pwrite` some data at some offset of a file with a given file descriptor. My data is stored in two vectors. One contains `unsigned long`s and the other `char`s.

I thought of building a `void *` that points to the bit sequence representing my `unsigned long`s and `char`s, and pass it to `pwrite` along with the accumulated size. But how can I cast an `unsigned long` to a `void*`? (I guess I can figure out for chars then). Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
void writeBlock(int fd, int blockSize, unsigned long offset){
  void* buf = malloc(blockSize);
  // here I should be trying to build buf out of vul and vc
  // where vul and vc are my unsigned long and char vectors, respectively.
  pwrite(fd, buf, blockSize, offset);
  free(buf);
}
```

Also, if you think my above idea is not good, I'll be happy to read suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot meaningfully cast an `unsigned long` to a `void *`. The former is a numeric value; the latter is the address of unspecified data. Most systems implement pointers as integers with a special type (that includes any system you're likely to encounter in day-to-day work) but the actual conversion between the types is considered harmful.

If what you want to do is write the value of an `unsigned int` to your file descriptor, you should *take the address* of the value by using the `&` operator:

```
unsigned int *addressOfMyIntegerValue = &myIntegerValue;
pwrite(fd, addressOfMyIntegerValue, sizeof(unsigned int), ...);
```

You can loop through your vector or array and write them one by one with that. Alternatively, it may be faster to write them en masse using `std::vector`'s contiguous memory feature:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> myVector = ...;
unsigned int *allMyIntegers = &myVector[0];
pwrite(fd, allMyIntegers, sizeof(unsigned int) * myVector.size(), ...);
```

Comment: Whoever's downvoting answers would do well to explain why they're downvoting.

Comment: What is going on with the -1s? +1

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only problem left for me is how to build my buf given that I need some combination of unsinged longs and chars and care much about efficiency, so I'd rather build my buf then pass it to pwrite to minimize I/O.

Comment: `pwrite()` will generally buffer writes. If you really want to do your own buffering, you should ask another question here, as it's beyond the scope of this one.

Answer (score 3):

```
unsigned long i;
void* p = (void*)&i;
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be cast using following code:

```
unsigned long my_long;
pwrite(fd, (void*)&my_long, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
std::vector<unsigned long> v1;
std::vector<char>          v2;

void * p1 = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&v1[0]);
void * p2 = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&v2[0]);
```

Write sizes `v1.size() * sizeof(unsigned long)` and `v2.size()`.